# SQL Server : CASE WHEN in the WHERE Clause with IN

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a been using some SQL for years now but requirements changed and I am having an issue updating the SQL. We need to use a different IN statement based on the `OrderCompletedDate`. If before 3/1/19, use on IN statement list and if after, use another. I thought it was a simple CASE WHEN, but not sure now.

Here is the code snippet:

```
SELECT
    CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ER.CreatedDateTime), 0) AS DATE) AS [MonthYear],
    COUNT(ER.RegistrationID) AS TotalCounts
FROM
    EventReg ER
WHERE 
    ER.OptedIn IS NOT NULL
    AND (ER.Phone IS NOT NULL or ER.CellPhone IS NOT NULL)
    AND (ER.BillingZip IN (CASE 
                              WHEN ER.CreatedDateTime >= '3/1/2019 12:00 AM' 
                                 THEN '12345', '45678', '90123'
                           END)
         OR ER.BillingZip NOT IN (CASE 
                                     WHEN ER.CreatedDateTime < '3/1/2019 12:00 AM' 
                                        THEN '07017', '07018',  '07019'
                                  END))
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ER.CreatedDateTime), 0)
ORDER BY 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ER.CreatedDateTime), 0) ASC
```

This is clearly not correct since you cannot have a list of items in the case/when, as I found out.  I wanted to wrap the CASE WHEN on the outside and then do the whole query inside each WHEN, but I just keep getting syntax errors.  EX:

```
AND (
   CASE 
     WHEN ER.CreatedDateTime >= '3/1/2019 12:00 AM' THEN 
       ER.BillingZip IN (
          '12345', '45678', '90123'
       )
     WHEN ER.CreatedDateTime < '3/1/2019 12:00 AM' THEN 
       ER.BillingZip NOT IN (
          '07017', '07018',  '07019'
       )
   END
)
```

The approach is probably wrong, but I cannot think of a way around it since we need to have the 3/1 break without two different queries altogether, which I am trying to avoid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use Charindex  function instead of in..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work using an OR

```
SELECT
   CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ER.CreatedDateTime), 0) AS DATE) AS [MonthYear],
   COUNT(ER.RegistrationID) AS TotalCounts
FROM
    EventReg ER
WHERE ER.OptedIn IS NOT NULL
AND (ER.Phone IS NOT NULL or ER.CellPhone IS NOT NULL)


AND (
        (
            ER.CreatedDateTime >= '3/1/2019 12:00 AM' 
            AND ER.BillingZip IN ('12345', '45678', '90123')
        )
        OR -- do OR here to do either one of these
        (
            ER.CreatedDateTime < '3/1/2019 12:00 AM'
            AND ER.BillingZip NOT IN ('07017', '07018',  '07019')
        )
    )


GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ER.CreatedDateTime), 0)
ORDER BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ER.CreatedDateTime), 0) ASC
```

Comment: This worked.  Sometimes you get an initial thought in your mind and go down this path not thinking the simplest, straightforward solution is right in front of you the whole time.  LOL.  Thanks Brad!!

Answer (score 3):

Just express this as boolean logic:

```
AND ( (ER.CreatedDateTime >= '2019-03-01' AND ER.BillingZip IN ('12345', '45678', '90123')) OR
      (ER.CreatedDateTime < '2019-03-01' AND ER.BillingZip NOT IN ('07017', '07018',  '07019'))
    )
```

Notice that I fixed the date format to be a standard format and the logic so it covers exactly midnight on 2019-03-01.